# Java HashMap in Python Code throwing Error

Tags: java, python, jmx

I need to use `HashMap` in Python code.

I am writing this line in Pycharm, using Python:

```
jhash = java.util.HashMap
```

I have imported like this:

```
import jpype
from jpype import java
from jpype import javax
```

But i am getting below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PythonCode/JMX.py", line 11, in <module>
  jhash = java.util.HashMap()
TypeError: Package `java.util.HashMap` is not callable.
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more code. Like the first 11 or 12 lines? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Even with this little code I could reproduce the error. In my opinion you didn't start JVM. This code works fine for me.

```
import jpype
from jpype import java

jpype.startJVM()
jhash = java.util.HashMap()
jhash.put("A","B")

print(jhash)
```

Comment: Thanks but using this code it is throwing error for jpype.startJVM as below:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonCode/venv/Scripts/p.py", line 4, in <module>
    jpype.startJVM()
  File "C:\PythonCode\venv\lib\site-packages\jpype\_core.py", line 178, in startJVM
    jvmpath = getDefaultJVMPath()
  File "C:\PythonCode\venv\lib\site-packages\jpype\_jvmfinder.py", line 74, in getDefaultJVMPath

Comment: Okay, what does ```jpype.getDefaultJVMPath()```give you?

Comment: This should return the path to your default JVM. If it's NONE you could code it hard in ```jpype.startJVM(PATH_TO_JVM)```. Don't mix 64Bit with 32Bit. SO if you use 64 bit python the JVM must be 62 bit too